# How to get max of a multiple columns based on other columns in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns, greatest-n-per-group, summarize

I have a dataframe like this.

| Name | Value1 | Numbr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Amy | 458 | 18652 |
| Tom | 6785 | 94632 |
| Rex | 9846 | 44967 |
| Tom | 1095 | 295633 |
| Rex | 3782 | 58362 |
| Amy | 1956 | 56280 |
| Rex | 8634 | 84592 |

I need to summarize this dataframe by name, get the maximum value of each two numerical column. Finally it should be a new dataframe. That is I want a table like this.

| Name | Value1 | Numbr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Amy | 1956 | 56280 |
| Rex | 9846 | 84592 |
| Tom | 6785 | 295633 |

Please help!

Comment: `dat %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarize(across(everything(), max))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by Name and then summarise applying `max`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  summarise(Value1 = max(Value1),
            Numbr = max(Numbr))
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Name  Value1  Numbr
  <chr>  <int>  <int>
1 Amy     1956  56280
2 Rex     9846  84592
3 Tom     6785 295633
```

Using R base `aggregate`

```
aggregate(cbind(Value1, Numbr) ~ Name, max, data=df)

  Name Value1  Numbr
1  Amy   1956  56280
2  Rex   9846  84592
3  Tom   6785 295633
```